Reflecting a fractal
Assume you have a certain IFS (iterated function system - a finite set of contractions) given by affine transformations.
As reflections are affine transformations, any reflection of an IFS fractal should be an IFS fractal too.
My question is, if the affine transformations are of the form
$$T(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} e\\ f \end{pmatrix}$$
How do you compute the set of $T'$ such that they generate, say, the reflection respect to the $X$ axis?
The composition with the reflection is not the answer. As an example, the Koch curve is given by:
$$\begin{align*}
T_1(x,y)&=\begin{pmatrix}1/3 & 0\\ 0 & 1/3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \\\\
T_2(x,y)&=\begin{pmatrix}1/6 & -\sqrt{3}/6\\ \sqrt{3}/6 & 1/6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 1/3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\\\\
T_3(x,y)&=\begin{pmatrix}1/6 & -\sqrt{3}/6\\ \sqrt{3}/6 & 1/6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 \\ 
 \sqrt{3}/6\end{pmatrix}\\\\
T_4(x,y)&=\begin{pmatrix}1/3 & 0\\ 0 & 1/3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}2/3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$
And its associated fractal is:

However, if you take $\{ST_1, ST_2, ST_3, ST_4\}$ as IFS, being $S$ the reflection respect to the $X$ axis, i.e. $S=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\ 0 &-1 \end{pmatrix}$, its associated fractal this chemical-like structure:


I believe that, if $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is an IFS with invariant set $K$ and $g$ is a homeomorphism on the same space, then you can generate $g(K)$ with the IFS obtained by conjugating the $f_i$s with $g$. That is use the IFS
$$\{g\circ f_i \circ g^{-1}\}_{i=1}^n.$$
If $g$ is a reflection, of course, then it is it's own inverse so that things are a bit simpler.
Here's an example that should make it easy to see why this works in general. Let's suppose that
$$\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\}$$
is the standard IFS that generates the Koch curve left to right. For example, $f_2$ could be the function that maps the whole Koch curve onto the orange portion shown here:

Now, let's let $g$ denote the function that rotates the plane about the origin through the angle $60^{\circ}$. If $K$ denotes the Koch curve, then I guess that $g(K)$ looks like so:

We now consider the conjugated IFS:
$$\{g\circ f_1 \circ g^{-1}, g\circ f_2 \circ g^{-1}, g\circ f_3 \circ g^{-1}, g\circ f_4 \circ g^{-1}\}.$$
We'd like to understand why that rotated version of the Koch curve is the invariant set of this conjugated IFS.
Let's focus, for example, on why the function
$$g\circ f_2 \circ g^{-1}$$
maps the whole rotated Koch curve onto that rotated orange part. That happens in three steps:

The function $g^{-1}$ rotates the whole rotated Koch curve $60^{\circ}$ back in the opposite direction so that it lands on the original Koch curve,
The function $f_2$ then maps the whole original Koch curve onto the un-rotated orange piece, and
Finally, the function $g$ rotates the un-rotated orange piece to the corresponding piece in the rotated Koch curve.

This illustrates the more general version; working with reflections is just a bit simpler.

I think your first assertion is not true, taking ${g\circ f_i\circ g_i^{-1}}$ doesn't generate $g(K)$ for the Koch curve in this case. If the $f_i$ are affine transformations $f_i(x)=A_ix + b_i$, then the set of $h_i(x) = g(A_i(g_i^{-1}(x)) + g(b_i)$ is the one that generates $g(K)$ (at least if $g$ is a reflection)

Yes, I think you're right.
